# Included PDF pages mess up page numbering in PDF-reader

Tags: numbering, pdf, include, count

I have a report with a frontpage, abstract, preface and acknowledgement. These pages are not numbered.
Then the remaining pages contain several chapters and all these pages are numbered.
Today I added however two PDF information pages between the frontpage and the abstract. That messed up the page numbering!
On paper everything is still okay, because the numbers are not printed on these pages, but when I view the document digitally with a PDF-reader then the page numbering starts on 1 with the first included PDF-page, the next included PDF page is page 2. The abstract, preface and acknowledgement pages from the original document have all become page 1.

Like this:

```
[code]
Frontpage = {page 1}
[Included PDF1] = Page 2
[Included PDF2] = Page 3
Abstract = Page 1
Preface = Page 1
Acknowledgement = Page 2
TOC = Page 3
[/code]
```

All pages up to the TOC used to be unnumbered, but now they have a page number with a value that is obviously wrong.
I am pretty sure the \pdfinclude command is responsible. I would like the numbering to start on the Acknowledgement or TOC page and continue without resetting the counter.
That is how it used to be, but the included PDF-pages mess up the numbering somehow and force the unnumbered pages to have page number 1.

How can I restore this to a normal page numbering like:

```
[code]
Frontpage = {no page number}
[Included PDF1] = {no page number}
[Included PDF2] = {no page number}
Abstract = Page {no page number}
Preface = Page 1
Acknowledgement = Page 2
TOC = Page 3
[/code]
```

A minimalistic code example:

```
[code]
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\input{./texfrontpage.tex}

\includepdf[pages={1,2}]{./pdf/information-page-one.pdf, ./pdf/information-page-two.pdf}

\begin{abstract}
  Interesting stuff.
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Background}

\chapter{Results}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
[/code]
```

To clarify: I do not want to include the page numbers of the two included PDF files nor do I want the page numbering to reset. I want the page numbers to start counting from the Preface of Acknowledgement page. That should be the first true page with page number 1. Everything before that should have no page number.

Comment: the minimal example you post don't produce the problem.

Comment: I altered the minimal example a bit. I forgot that I use an abstract environment instead of a \chapter*. 
There are many packages that I use but I am pretty sure that the problem occurs with the current minimalized example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. With `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\input{./texfrontpage.tex}

\includepdf[pages={1,2}]{./pdf/information-page-one.pdf, ./pdf/information-page-two.pdf}

\begin{abstract}
  Interesting stuff.
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Background}

\chapter{Results}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The trim is intended to remove the page number from the pdf pages?
My pdf-pages actually do not contain page numbers. I think I have not made myself clear.

Comment: @TexTiel No its my bad (see edit). so you don't need this part.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The trim is intended to remove the page number from the pdf pages?
My pdf-pages actually do not contain page numbers. I think I have not made myself clear. 
It is not about the page numbers displayed (or not) ON the page. The problem lies in the fact that the PDF-viewer application numbers the pages wrong.
The typical overview or thumbnail view on the side shows wrong page numbers. Some of them share the page number 1. They are therefore not unique.
Trimming is a visual hack that does not solve the actual page numbering problem in the overview toolbar.

Comment: @TexTiel I edit my answer. Please add informations above to your post.